# How can I fetch the user information by getting it from the order userId

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, object, axios, mern

How can I grab the information of customers by using userId? I tried to create another useEffect, but It's not working, and I'm having trouble on how can I map it on the division if I already use orders.map()

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { userRequest } from "../../requestMethod";
import "./widgetLg.css";

export default function WidgetLg() {
  const Button = ({ type }) => {
    return <button className={"widgetLgButton " + type}>{type}</button>;
  };

  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getOrders = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("orders");
        setOrders(res.data)
        const userInfo = await userRequest.get("user/find/61ab2c6826a0dd9359e185e0")
    ///    console.log(userInfo.data)

      } catch {
        console.log("Error")
      }
    };
    getOrders();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() =>{
    const getUserInfo = async () =>{
      try {
        const userInfo = await userRequest.get('user/find/'+orders._id)
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
    }
    getUserInfo()
  },[])
  
  return (
    
    <div className="widgetLg">
      <h3 className="widgetLgTitle">Latest transactions</h3>
      <table className="widgetLgTable">
        <tbody>

        <tr className="widgetLgTr">
          <th className="widgetLgTh">Customer</th>
          <th className="widgetLgTh">Date</th>
          <th className="widgetLgTh">Amount</th>
          <th className="widgetLgTh">Status</th>
        </tr>
        {orders.map((order) =>(
          <tr className="widgetLgTr" key={order._id}>
          <td className="widgetLgUser">
            <img
              src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4172933/pexels-photo-4172933.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
              alt=""
              className="widgetLgImg"
              />
            <span className="widgetLgName"> Username </span>
          </td>
          <td className="widgetLgDate">{order.createdAt}</td>
          <td className="widgetLgAmount">${order.amount}</td>
          <td className="widgetLgStatus">
            <Button type={order.status} />
          </td>
        </tr>
              ))}
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Sorry, I'm not really good at explaining it in English. I tried to crop it and draw a line to visualize it further more. Thanks for the help

Comment: So you want to get all userIds from your orders and use them to get data from server?

Comment: yes, @kianjalilian. and then I will render the data and grab the username and show it to the latest transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of all userIds like this:

```
 const userIds = orders.map(order => order.userId);
```

If you want user information for all the users in userIds, you shouldn't send requests seperately because you will experience long delays and response time in your application.

I would suggest that you either write an api in backend that takes array of userIds and returns data of all those users at once, or populate the username of user in your orders if you only need the username.